# Scrapy modify cookie

Tags: cookies, scrapy

I'm able to create a cookie with scrapy but unable to modify one existing cookie.
In the ecommerce website i'm working, this cookie handles the postal code and the postal is used by each page to modify product attributes. I can modify the postal code using selenium, scrape every page, but the scrape process is too slow. I wanted to use scrapy only, modifying this request/response postcode cookie.

I can create a cookie on my requests using this code

in SETTINGS.PY
COOKIES_ENABLED = True

in spider.py
yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parsePage, cookies={'cp': codpost})

I get the list of cookies using:
cookies = response.headers.getlist("Set-Cookie")

The relevant result I get on every page is:
[..., b'cp=28029; Expires=Sun, 29-Feb-2032 07:58:44 GMT; Path=/', ...]

It doesn't look like to be a pair key/value. How can I modify this cookie? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to manually modify the cookies, you probably can get through using [cookiejar](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#multiple-cookie-sessions-per-spider).

You can yield several requests for different postal codes, and include a different cookiejar in each request, that way Scrapy will manage different sessions for each request.

```
for code in postal_code:
    yield Request(url, meta={'cookiejar': code}, callback=self.callback_func)
```

This is a minimal example, just to show how to pass the cookiejar in the request. Keep in mind that the values represented by `code` must be different for each different session you need.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and guiding. I know nothing about cookiejar. Can you elaborate a little more or guide me where to learn about cookiejar? Anyway I will investigate from my side to see if I can solve my problem. Just to clarify my problem: when I run a spider session I'm only interested in one codpost, no need to make requests form multiple codposts in the same session

Comment: I intend to pass the codpost as an argument to the spider and run for this codpost